# Bad URI(is not URI?) on updating user model if avatar URL has a whitespace

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, image-uploading

I'm using carrierwave to upload images to s3 as an avatar for users, the image is been uploaded correctly, but when I try to update the user model I got an error if the url of uploaded image has a whitespace:

```
URI::InvalidURIError
bad URI(is not URI?): https://files.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/110/111134a0-25d6-0130-f023-60eb69762222/photo copy.jpg
```

What is the better way to solve this? 
I'm using carrierwave, fog, carrierwave_direct and rmagick to upload images.

[UPDATE:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::]

After reading this "[carrierwave fails to load certain url](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/764)" I added in `AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` :

```
def process_uri(uri) 
  URI.parse(URI.escape(URI.unescape(uri))) 
end
```

But didn't work, It seems that this approach is correct, but keeps saving in the DB the url image with whitespace instead "%20".

Answer (score 1):

Use URI.escape to clean up the URL before you validate it.

```
1.9.3p327 > URI.escape "https://files.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/110/111134a0-25d6-0130-f023-60eb69762222/photo copy.jpg"
 => "https://files.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/110/111134a0-25d6-0130-f023-60eb69762222/photo%20copy.jpg"
```

Comment: I did something like that in `AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` I added:
  
  `def process_uri(uri)
    URI.parse(URI.escape(URI.unescape(uri)))
   end`

[carrierwave fails to load certain url](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/764) 

But didn't work, It seems that this approach is correct, but keeps saving in the DB the url image with whitespace instead %20.